# When is "an established connection" supposed to be true in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

Can't figure this one out:

In the `DB_driver.php` (core system/database)

this is beginning of init function...

```
    /**
     * Initialize Database Settings
     *
     * @return  bool
     */
    public function initialize()
    {
        /* If an established connection is available, then there's
         * no need to connect and select the database.
         *
         * Depending on the database driver, conn_id can be either
         * boolean TRUE, a resource or an object.
         */
        if ($this->conn_id)
        {
            return TRUE;
        }

        // ----------------------------------------------------------------

        // Connect to the database and set the connection ID
        $this->conn_id = $this->db_connect($this->pconnect);
```

The `initialize()` is called wihtin `CI_Controller` so when creating new objects for example like this:

```
$x = new PartyPooper();
$y = new PartyPooper();
```

`initialize()` in the `DB_driver` is called twice. Nothing strange with that, but I would expect `$this->conn_id` to be set when creating `PartyPooper()` object second time (`$y`)?

When is "an established connection" supposed to be true? (In the example two database connections are made when there would should only be one?)

I'm using the latest database drivers in the development branch: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/tree/develop/system/database

I am using the mysqli-driver with persistant connections of.

**UPDATE:**

I'm not a huge fan messing with core-files, but I couldn't figure out another solution here. Please tell me if there's a better way of achieving of what I want to do.

I came up with this code (using sessions to handle storing and checking for existing db-connections (of the "subdriver"-object. (mysqli object in my case)):

```
public function initialize()
{
        /* If an established connection is available, then there's
         * no need to connect and select the database.
         *
         * Depending on the database driver, conn_id can be either
         * boolean TRUE, a resource or an object.
         */                 
        if ($this->conn_id) {
                return TRUE;
        }

        $conn_session_id_name = 'dbsession_conn';      
        if (isset($_SESSION[$conn_session_id_name])) {
                $sess = $_SESSION[$conn_session_id_name];

                // Set connection id object or resourse and return true
                // because no more connecting has to be done
                if (is_object($sess) || is_resource($sess)) {                        
                        $this->conn_id = $sess;
                        return TRUE;
                }
        }
            // Connect to the database and set the connection ID
        $this->conn_id = $this->db_connect($this->pconnect);

        // Store conn object or resource etc into session                
        if (is_object($this->conn_id) || is_resource($this->conn_id)) {
                $_SESSION[$conn_session_id_name] = $this->conn_id;
        }

        // No connection resource? Check if there is a failover else throw an error                 
            if ( ! $this->conn_id)
            {               
            //rest of code as before...
```

My application got extremly much faster because it used one connection instead of around 60.

But my original question remains:

When is this supposed to be true in the `initialize()` function?

```
if ($this->conn_id) {
    return TRUE;
}
```

(I didn't remove it when changing the code because I suppose it has some purpose-but even if I can't figure out which)

**UPDAtE2** - clarification:

In a model I have a db select statement that is supposed to return PartyPooper objects:

eg. `$res = $q->result('PartyPooper');`

This PartyPooper is a controller that stores information about people, like names, years , birthdays etc, but it also handles stuff like calculation of info within the same object.

```
class PartyPooper extends CI_Controller { .... }
```

But as I understand from the comments below I should do like this instead?

```
class PartyPooper extends CI_Controller { .... }
class PartyPooperObject { .... } //Store information about people in this object
```

eg. `$res = $q->result('PartyPooperObject');`

Comment: Why is your `PartyPooper` class actually calling the initializer of a **controller** class? Controllers are the things which handle requests. They are not meant to model "normal" objects. If your class definition is `class PartyPooper extends CI_Controller`, you should change that. Otherwise please add the line, so we can see the relationships between your class and the rest of CodeIgniter.

Comment: yes it extends to CI_Controller. In the PartyPooper class it handles requests to PartyPooper model class (which handles database-request). What should I change extend CI_Controller to?

Comment: Well if it is a controller, it should extend the `CI_Controller` class. But there should be only one controller object per request ...  why do you have multiple of them? Normally the routing code creates a controller object, which glues models and views together and returns the response. So one request, one controller object.

Comment: hm. I think I was mixing things up here. Thanks for your feedback. I will have to create a PartyPooper Object (without extending CI_Controller) which stores the actual data of each PartyPooper object and then a PartyPooper Controller which handles other stuff like calculation of data in all PartyPooper objects and such things?

Comment: But even if that is true, my original question still remains. when is $this->conn_id supposed to be true in the initialize() function ?

Comment: I am not sure what you implement, so I can mostly guess... you would create a controller class in most cases for e.g. the PartyPoopCreate-Page at `example.com/partypooopcreator/`. You would create a model class in most cases for the mysql table `party_poopers`, which allows easy access to store elements in the database. In the best case the controller class only calls easy methods of the model class and the model class contains all computations concerning ParyPooper-objects of the database.

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at some easy demo MVC application tutorials. [Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/codeigniter-getting-started-with-a-simple-example) is one.

Comment: Updated my question. I hope it gets clearer what I want to achieve.

Comment: Yes, this would be more right. Although I am still not sure what you need the additional class for. Why can't you just create a normal model class, which should handle the information concerning a person? For what do you need a `PartyPoop` model AND an `PartyPoopObject` simultaneously (besides the new `PartyPoop` controller)?

Comment: Ok thanks! Basically this is the thing: $this->result('PartyPooperObject') creates new objects from another model) and not new models and therefore I must have that info in a class?

Comment: Yes...? But a model also is a class, so you could just pass a model name to `result` and let the method create model objects instead of your custom objects. If you use a custom class, you must take care of saving and deleting rows from the database by yourself.

Comment: Aaaaaaaah so it should be $this->result('PartyPooperModel') instead? (For some reason I thought $this->result() could only be applied to controllers (not models). I didn't make the connection between those two that both are actually classes)

Comment: Yes, this would make sense to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code

```
    if ($this->conn_id) {
            return TRUE;
    }
```

just assures that the `initialize` method is only called **once** *per object*.

If it has been called on the current object already, it must not be executed another time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answers the actual question I hade, but thanks for the other help as well and getting my on the right track. I thought something was very wrong when I had to hack into core files...